# Checking Form Validation While User Fills Out Form Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have created a form with validation checking using,

```
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
```

Currently I have the `Submit button` `[disabled]` till the form is filled out correctly. The only way I am showing the user if the form is valid or not is by showing red in the input when the form field is not valid.

[image]

I would like to display an error message to the user to show them what is wrong.

Is there something built into Angular2 to show the error message or why the input field is not valid? Or do I need to built custom error messages for each form field? If so how would I go about checking each input field, let's say when someone leaves focus from the respective field. So if they leave the input field and it was not valid then I can display a message telling them it was not valid and why?

I have a method to show the message I just need to come up with a way to obtain and error message. In other words produce the text from the form on why it is not valid.

**Example**

```
Please provide a valid mobile number
```

**Code**

**REGEX**

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.personalForm = new FormGroup({
            email : new FormControl(this.auth.user.email,Validators.required ),
            first_name: new FormControl(null,[
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü']{1,30}$")
            ]),
            middle_name: new FormControl(null,[
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü']{1,30}$")
            ]),

            last_name: new FormControl(null,[
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü']{1,30}$")
            ]),

            dob : new FormControl (null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("[1][9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]|[2][0][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]")
            ]),
            mobile_phone: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
            ]),
            home_phone: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
            ]),

            business_phone: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
            ]),
            fax_number: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
            ]),
            ssn: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
            ])
        });
    }
```

**Valid Boolean / Handle The Form Data**

```
save(model: Personal, isValid: boolean) {
        if (!isValid) {
            console.log('Personal Form is not valid');
            console.log(model, isValid);
        } else {
            console.log('Personal Form is valid');
            console.log(model, isValid);
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return this.http
                .post('http://localhost:4200/api/updateProfile',
                    model,
                    {headers: headers})
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe((res) => {
                    //do something with the response here
                    console.log(res);
                });
        }
    }
```

**Form**

```
<form [formGroup]="personalForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(personalForm.value, personalForm.valid)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="card card-inverse card-success">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <strong>Personal Information</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
          </span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="{{personal.email}}"readonly>
                            </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!personalForm.controls.email.valid && submitted ">
                                *Email is required.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: This can all be handled in the HTML template.  Can you please post your form template.

Comment: I added a piece of the form so you could se.e

Comment: I think I see how I can control this know making custom errors. But the most information I can get from the form the better. I guess to save myself time. Please see this line !personalForm.controls.middle_name.valid && submitted  Notice the controls. is this built in to FormControl? SO I can call each object in the FormControls I built? I am doing that right correct?

Comment: You are doing it correctly.  That's what I was getting at with wanting to see your template.  Yes, it's built into FormGroup/FormControl.

Comment: Well do you see in my save() method I have a boolean? Do I need to use that boolean to check each input for error client side? I still cant even get the alerts to show up. So a few things I need to be clear on, is controls built in? So I am accessing it right? personalForm.controls.first_name ?? Is not? I saw a tutorial use that and it made sense it was built in but I have not see it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

To access the `FormGroup` `input` fields you can use `syntax` to access the `controls` you have created.

```
this.FormGroupName.get('ControlName').status
```

That will return `VALID` or `INVALID`

In my case this is how it was done,

**Example**

Import correct packages,

```
import {FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import {INVALID, VALID} from "@angular/forms/src/model";
```

Create `FormGroup`,

```
personalForm: FormGroup;
```

Create `FormControl`,

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.personalForm = new FormGroup({
            first_name: new FormControl(null,[
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü']{1,30}$")
            ]),
   });
}
```

Add the `FormControlName` to the `form` and the `function` to call when you want the `error` to be checked.

```
<input (blur)="firstNameValidate('*First Name Required', 'Use 1-30 letters to spell your name.')" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first name" id="first_name" formControlName="first_name">
```

Check for `VALID` or `INVALID`,

```
firstNameValidate(ErrorTitle, ErrorMessage) {
        if (this.personalForm.get('first_name').status == VALID) {
            this.getSuccess("First Name Entered", "First name entered correctly");
        } else {
            this.toastWarning(ErrorTitle, ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

**Calling Errors**

In my case I decided to show my errors in a `toast`. So I used `blur` to track when the user leaves an `input` field. When the user moves out of an `input` field the `firstNameValidate()` function is called and the correct `toast` is displayed based on the value, `VALID` or `INVALID`. Depending on the `response` one of these two `functions` is fired off.

```
toastWarning(ErrorTitle, ErrorMessage) {
        var toastOptions:ToastOptions = {
            title: ErrorTitle,
            msg: ErrorMessage,
            showClose: true,
            timeout: 7000,
            theme: 'bootstrap',
            onAdd: (toast:ToastData) => {
                console.log('Toast ' + toast.id + ' has been added!');
            },
            onRemove: function(toast:ToastData) {
                console.log('Toast ' + toast.id + ' has been removed!');
            }
        };
            this.toastyService.warning(toastOptions);
        }

    getSuccess(SuccessTitle, SuccessMessage) {
        var toastOptions:ToastOptions = {
            title: SuccessTitle,
            msg: SuccessMessage,
            showClose: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            theme: 'bootstrap',
            onAdd: (toast:ToastData) => {
                console.log('Toast ' + toast.id + ' has been added!');
            },
            onRemove: function(toast:ToastData) {
                console.log('Toast ' + toast.id + ' has been removed!');
            }
        };
        this.toastyService.success(toastOptions);
    }
```

Then the user sees the correct `toast` / `message`,

**Success**

[image]

**Warning**

[image]